# Selenium PHP Webdriver - Not Catching Exceptions?

Tags: php, selenium, selenium-webdriver

**What's the proper way to catch exceptions using the PHP Webdriver?** I have something like this:

```
try {
    // Throws a NoSuchElementException if id doesn't exist 
    $driver->findElement(WebDriverBy::id('loggedIn'));
    return TRUE;
}
catch (NoSuchElementException $e) {
    // id='loggedIn' doesn't exist
    return FAlSE;
}
catch (Exception $e)
{
    // Unknown exception
    return FALSE;
}
```

However, when I reach a page and do not find the element with the `id` I'm looking for, I get the following error:

> Uncaught Facebook\WebDriver\Exception\NoSuchElementException: Unable
>   to locate element: #loggedIn

I'm not sure why as my code is wrapped in a try-catch block.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I would suggest you avoid `try..catch` and check whether the element is on the page without getting an exception, just try using `findElements` instead which would return either an array of all elements with matching locator or empty array if nothing is found, so you need to just check the array count to determine that element exists or not as below :-

```
if (count($driver->findElements(WebDriverBy::id("loggedIn"))) > 0) 
{
  return TRUE;
}else 
{
  return FALSE;
}
```

Comment: That's a possible workaround for `findElement`, but it doesn't answer why I'm not able to catch exceptions.

Comment: Ok make sure you are catching right `NoSuchElementException`. Verify first are you imported correct class for `NoSuchElementException`??

Comment: And also make sure exception is throwing from this code or some other code which is not inside `try..catch` block??

Answer (score 4):

this works for me, hope this helps someone

```
try {
    ...
} catch (Exception\NoSuchElementException) {
    ...
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I am  not sure , why neither  Exception,  nor specific exception does not  work ,  but :

catch    (WebDriverException $e)

works for me )